# What degree of randomness is required for a stochastic policy learning task?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, randomness

I am working on an reinforcement learning training task:
My policy network is LSTM+Gumbel-Softmax, so the sampled policy (i.e. a list of discrete categorical intergers) can be differentiable.
The obtained policy will interract with the environment to generate a final overall accuracy (The goal here is to improve some classification performance).

However, due to the randomness of Gumbel, the training/validation curves look super noisy and it always fluctuates. However, if I deliberately fixed random seed to 0 for each input sample, the curves are stable and achieved a decent validation accuracy.

My objective is for enigneering, instead of publishing or claiming a better method than others. But I understand the ideal scenario is that, I don't set a seed at all, and learning just gave me a nice model which works for any seeds.

My experiment is like this:  During training, I reset random seed to 0 before each input sample enters the network.  During testing, I also reset random seed to 0 before each test sample enters the network. And the final accuracy is high for test samples (However, if I change to a different seed, the accuracy can be really low).

Could someone provide some comments and feedback whether my experiment is correct? Can I use the above trained model with seed (0) for real world prediction tasks?  My feeling is that, if I zoom out to view this as a normal deep-learning task (training data and testing data are separated and test accuracy looks decent), I don't see any problems. But it is kind of scary that my model has to work with random seed fixed to 0.